# Backpropagation through time for stacked RNNs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms, backpropagation, calculus

I was able to find the partial derivative of the cost function with respects to a single variable without much difficulty. However, this requires propagating backwards through the network for each parameter. Is there a way to do this by propagating backwards through the network once? For example, for a MLP, one could find the partial derivative with respects to the activation levels of neurones by propagation backwards only once, and then finding the partial derivatives of the weights and biases by applying the chain rule. Unfortunately, for a stacked RNN, this proved way less straightforward due to the parameters being the same at each time step. I think it might have something to do with ordered derivatives but can’t seem to find much resources on the topic.

Comment: you're familiar with how backprop can be applied on any computation involving "primitive" operations such as addition, multiplication, tanh, other simple functions, and matrix-vector multiplication (as in a linear layer), right? well, since (stacked) RNNs are also composed of such primitive operations, the exact same backprop algorithm can, with no modifications, also backprop through it.

Comment: @shimao thanks for the response. However, the problem for me was not backpropagation itself but more how to do it in one scoop. Do you know the alogithm for this?

Comment: I thought only the order of the sequence differs here. In the vanilla RNN the order is defined by the original order but here the order is controlled by the shift and reduce operations.